# PhpStorm markdown preview window - font way too small

Tags: phpstorm, markdown

I am using the latest PhpStorm 2016.3 on Windows.  While editing a markdown file, I noticed there is a preview window (that I am fairly sure is new, but it has been awhile since I edited markdown).  Unfortunately, it looks like this, where the right side preview is unreadable:

[image]

I have set up `Settings->Editor->Colors and Fonts->Font` to be Source Code Pro, size 28 long ago to handle my 4K monitor.  And I found `Settings->Editor->Colors and Fonts->Markdown` where I can change the look of the left side, but not the right.  So I have two questions:

- Is anyone else seeing this (standard or 4K monitor)?
- Is there a setting that I can change?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160467 *I guess* -- seems referring to the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, it turns out it is a JetBrains plugin and they had automatically turned off the plug in that I had installed.  But, your comment got me to hunt further and found the setting, I'm putting in an answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I found out that JetBrains has a plugin named "Markdown Support", so it is important to make sure only that plugin is installed by checking `Settings->Plugins`.

I was using a third-party plugin before and I believe it was turned off automatically during upgrade.  When I tried to turn it back on, and restarted PhpStorm, a prompt appeared indicating the two plugins were incompatible and I had to choose one, so I chose the JetBrains plugin.

Then, `Settings->Language & Frameworks->Markdown->Preview`, change the `Preview browser` field to `JavaFX WebView`.  And the preview pane is back to the land of readable fonts.